# The rank of the intersection of subgroups of a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be finitely generated subgroups of a free group $F$, and suppose that $H$ has finite index in $F$. Is it true that $rank(H \cap K)-1 \leq (rank(H)-1)(rank(K)-1)$?

Comment: (actually, I missed the "finite-index" part, so ignore my deleted comment).

Comment: @mary seva, it looks like your question is about to be closed (and/or migrated) as 'not research level'.  In fact, I think it is graduate-student level, and hence acceptable on MO.  But I suspect the formulation, which reads like a homework problem, has irritated the voters to close. Could you tell us how this problem arises in your research?

Comment: While this is certainly not a great question, why does it get THAT many downvotes?

Comment: @StefanKohl I am guessing because it looks like homework.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this statement is true and for a long time was known as the [Hanna Neumann Conjecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanna_Neumann_conjecture) It was proved in 2011 by Igor Mineyev.

Comment: You voted to close and posted an answer -- I wonder how does this fit together?

Comment: @StephanKohl The first response was knee-jerk, the second was a result of some thought. There is no way to retract a close vote, as far as I know.

Comment: @StefanKohl I did just ask to reopen, if it makes you feel any better.

Comment: @StefanKohl, if it is really important to you, you may open a question on Meta, the question being why was this closed, the request being please vote to re-open. For myself, I get very tired of newcomers paying no attention to the norms of the site...and we have a tidal wave of that since joining stackexchange in full, as MO 2.0. Finally, as Igor came up with an answer, I also see little need to re-open. Meanwhile, I really dislike it when someone posts a question and wanders off.

Comment: Igor, it was asked about the case, where one of the subgroups is of **finite index**. This is indeed an exercise on Schreier formula.

Comment: @AntonKlyachko Ah, OK, I did not read carefully...

Comment: @WillJagy What do you mean "wanders off"? The question was asked just three hours ago.

Comment: @WillJagy: I just found it worth noting, not more.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, the first hour with no response to feedback was enough for me. I gather you feel differently.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I do. A "normal person" (not a fanatic like you or me (-:) might post, go about their usual day, and maybe check back in the evening when there's a spare moment. Personally I think getting back within 24 hours is fine, but I feel some impatience if it takes more than 48 hours.

Comment: By the way, Friedman also gave a correct proof of the Hanna Neumann Conjecture (after a couple of incorrect attempts).

Comment: @ToddTrimble, there's your 24 hours. 11:30 PST, it does not seem to give minutes; I think "yesterday" means 24 hours rather than 23.5.

Comment: @WillJagy Yep, there it is. That's a shame.